# Date Picker in Google Apps script does not have timezone selection

Tags: google-apps-script, datepicker, google-workspace-add-ons

I am trying to create a date picker from Cardservice in google apps script. The date picker has an option to set a default value like the following. However, there is no option to set the time zone and it takes GMT by default and it shows the wrong date value for my time zone. Someone tell is there a way to specify timezone or suggest some alternates.

```
CardService.newDatePicker()
.setFieldName(Task_SupportFields[I])
.setTitle(Bug_SupportFields[I])
.setValueInMsSinceEpoch(<some epoch value>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `CardService` offers you both a `DatePicker()` and a `DateTimePicker()`

If you use [`DateTimePicker()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/date-time-picker) instead of `DatePicker()` you can specify [`setTimeZoneOffsetInMins()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/date-time-picker#settimezoneoffsetinminstimezoneoffsetmins) for offset from UTC.

Comment: Yeah I know that man, I just want the date picker.
Is there a way to adjust the epoch value to a particular time zone before setting it in the date picker?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not such a method. Think about it - the date picker only allows the user to set a date, not a time, so it does not matter in which time zone the user is. However, when you retrieve the values, you can adjust the time zone offset to your local time zone.